# Integrating Angular with ExtJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, extjs

I want to create a popup using angularjs in Extjs Page.This is my current situation.I have manually bootstrapped angular link when they click.now the issue is ext-all.css and bootstrap.css files are conflicting.So How can i avoid this conflict.Can any one suggest idea?any conflict arise in js file if its in same page? Lot of thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[AngularJS + ExtJS - another question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447359/is-it-possible-to-use-extjs-components-in-angularjs) read this before considering to combine both.

I have tried doing it for my websites for curiosity's sake but it creates more problems then it solves. I would strongly recommend sticking to one framework.

You can combine Jquery and ExtJS without problems because they do not have any conflicting elements.

Your conflict probably arises from the same naming and calling that might or might not exist within the libraries of these two frameworks. The way I see to fix it would be to go within a library and start solving the conflicts. That will be very tedious to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really mix these frameworks together in a single project. ExtJs is a fully fledged component based framework which should provide most, if not all the functionality that you need. If you are missing something then you should look at the Sencha forums section on user plugins and extensions or even build it yourself.

ExtJs provides most, if not all of the functionality of AngularJs already but adds visual components such as grids, forms, windows, treepanels etc. If your using Ext already for your project you should really stick by it. Adding another framework adds complexity and additional libraries to download, increasing load times etc.